# How do i get mapview to plot my raster image with the same colors as plotRGB or plot

Tags: r, r-raster, r-leaflet, r-mapview

I have a raster [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hjv7egnfjkfhozl/KYENGERA.tif?dl=0) that I have exported from ArcGIS as a georeferenced tif file.
The raster will be used as a background map in mapview because the mapview background layers CartoDB.Positron,  CartoDB.DarkMatter,  OpenStreetMap , Esri.WorldImagery and  OpenTopoMapdont dont give the required background at the zoom level i need.

First I read my raster brick into R using the raster package and then I plot using plotRGB.

```
library(raster)
library(mapview)
r<-brick("KYENGERA2.tif")#raster exported from Arcgis read. has 4 bands
r<-subset(r,1:3) #Retain only layers/bands with RGB
plotRGB(r, 1,2,3, stretch='lin')
```

The result is as expected
[image]

I then create a new raster r2 with values 0 - 255 and assign a colortable based on the rgb values in r. I plot it in two difefrent ways and i get the same result.

```
pct <- rgdal::SGDF2PCT(as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))
r2 <- setValues(raster(r), pct$idx-1) #create a new raster with values 0 - 255
colortable(r2) <- pct$ct #define 256 colors
plotRGB(r, 1,2,3, stretch='lin')
plot(r2)#plot(r2,col=r2@legend@colortable)
```

Here is the result and it is much better
[image]

However when I try mapview, the result is not as expected.

```
mapview(r2, col.regions = pct$ct,na.col="transparent")
```

[image]

**Can anyone help me solve this issue with mapview?**
I have taken a look at [this](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/208) but i couldnt figure out a solution.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot reproduce your example, because we don't have `pct`

Comment: I forgot a couple of lines pct <- rgdal::SGDF2PCT(as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `mapview::viewRGB()`

```
viewRGB(r, 1, 2, 3, method = "ngb", quantiles = c(0, 1), maxpixels = ncell(r))
```

Comment: using ```viewRGB``` gives ```Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': NA```. I had tried this earlier and that is why i decided to code as above.

Comment: Did you `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/mapview")`?

Comment: This didnt work. `Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'extent': NA
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
2: In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition`

Comment: I think it's best to open an issue on https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview. One last thing you can try beforehand is `remotes::install_github("r-spatial/leafem")` and see if that solves it. If it doesn't, please open an issue on github.